I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 24.04LTS and screen turned black after login ,machine is still running , acer laptop with i5 8thgen and 220mx nvidia
I tried a option like in grub file by removing the quiet splash and setting it to empty string , even after doing it still black screen is there. I don't know what to do the Machine even hangs in the login page, I m no expert in the Linux but kind of like it over the windows, but if it keep of giving things like this I will keep on loosing important data
